# SQLite in-memory database not being destroyed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I wrote this extremely simple test script to examine the functionality of in-memory shared cache databases, and it seems that the database is not being cleaned up after the script exits.

```
import sqlite3

def hello():
    db = sqlite3.connect('file::memory:?cache=shared')
    db.execute("CREATE TABLE test (hello varchar(32))")
    db.execute("INSERT INTO test (hello) VALUES ('world')")
    db.commit()
    c1 = db.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
    print c1.fetchone()
    db.close()

def world():
    wdb = sqlite3.connect('file::memory:?cache=shared')
    c = wdb.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
    print c.fetchone()
    wdb.close()


hello()
world()
```

The first time I ran this script, it worked without issue, but I had forgotten the close calls. The second time I ran it, I got an exception saying that the table already exists. I know, obviously, that I can add `IF NOT EXISTS` to the `CREATE TABLE` statement to make this go away, but this behavior would seem to imply that the database is still in memory somehow. Am I interpreting this correctly? If so, is there any way to get it cleaned up?

I've tried commenting the queries and simply opening/closing the connections, but that didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python sqlite3 module in Python 2.7 does not support URI filenames. `db = sqlite3.connect('file::memory:?cache=shared')` actually creates a file on disk called "file::memory:?cache=shared", and you connect to that each time.

Instead, just do `db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')`, although you won't get the shared cache behaviour.

This behaviour [has been fixed](https://bugs.python.org/issue13773), but only in Python 3.4, and you need to pass the `uri=True` kwarg.

Comment: I was struggling with the same issue just to realize that I forgot to add a column after the "memory" ending up with a disk file named ":memory".